# Remove all joins from a layer using pyqgis

Tags: pyqgis, attribute-joins

The title says it all. I want to remove all joins from a layer.

After examining the QGIS API documentation and playing a bit with the QgsVectorLayer class I've figured out how to do it but my doubt is whether there's a better way to do this same thing. I haven't found a single example using `QgsVectorLayer.vectorJoins` nor anything related to identifying which tables are joined to a layer so I don't know if this is actually the way to go.

```
for layer in QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayers().values():
    if layer.name() == "Fire Halls":
        fh_lyr = layer

joinsInfo = fh_lyr.vectorJoins()
for joinInfo in joinsInfo:
    ok = fh_lyr.removeJoin(joinInfo.joinLayerId)
    if ok:
        progress.setInfo(u'Join removed successfully')
    else:
        msg = "Couldn't remove the layer join"
        raise GeoAlgorithmExecutionException(msg)
```