# Removing a joined layer using PyQGIS?

Tags: pyqgis, attribute-joins

I have two layers that I want to remove using PyQGis as part of a larger script. The first layer I can removed using:

```
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().removeMapLayer( shp.id() )
```

However, it seems that the second layer (the Joined layer) cannot be removed in the same way as I get the following error:

```
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().removeMapLayer( result.id() )

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: JoinAttributes instance has no attribute 'id'
```

Does anyone happen to know a way to remove the Joined layer with PyQGIS?

Comment: what kind of object is your **"result"** and where does it come from ? hard to answer without seeing a bit more of your code.

Comment: My result is the Joined layer. It is a shapefile that comes from joining a .csv with a previously made "base" shapefile.

Comment: could you show the line generating this "result" ?

Comment: Of course, result = processing.runandload('qgis:joinattributestable', shp, csv, shpField, csvField, None). The shp and csv are the variables where the shapefile and csv are stores. They are csv = QgsVectorLayer(csv_location, '2003day303', 'delimitedtext') and shp =  QgsVectorLayer(shp_location, 'Alberta Zones test', 'ogr') respectively.

Comment: the shpField and csvField represent the unique ID in the shapefile and csv allowing for the join to happen

Comment: Have you tried this method?  https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/221554/remove-all-joins-from-a-layer-using-pyqgis

Answer (score 3, accepted):

U used the toolbox algorithm **"qgis:joinattributestable"**.

This algorithm creates a new table named **Joined layer** (i don't know whether the algorithm let u choose its name ...)

**Result** is not a reference to any **QgsVectorLayer** but is a **JoinAttributes** instance which enables you to retrieve some information about the algorithm you just launched.

So `result.id` generates an error since **id** is not an attribute of this class.

**RemoveAllMapLayers** looks really like an odd solution to me ... better use something like :

```
jl = QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayersByName("Joined layer")[0]
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().removeMapLayer(jl.id())
```

Answer (score 3):

After working on the problem for a little while longer I was able to find an answer, although not an ideal one.

What I ended up doing was using

```
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().removeAllMapLayers()
```

to remove all the map layers, and then afterwards re-adding the ones I need.

While this does get the job done, it probably isn't the most elegant or efficient solution. If anyone knows a better way please post it.